# How to access to object methods when you pass an object as a parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

How can I call a method of an object passed as a parameter in PHP?

This is the first class defined in thefirstclass.php

```
class TheFirstClass {

    private $_city='Madrid';

    public function city() {
        return $_city
    }   
}
```

This is the second class defined in thesecondclass.php

```
class TheSecondClass {

    public function myMethod($firstClassObject) {

        echo "City: " . $firstClassObject->city(); // <- Why This method doesn´t work?      

    }
}
```

And finally, this is 
    include_once "class/thefirstclass.php";
    include_once "class/thesecondclass.php";

```
$firstClassObject = new TheFirstClass();
$secondClassObject = new TheSecondClass();

$secondClassObject->myMethod($firstClassObject);
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *does not work*? Maybe I'm too drunk but it should.

Comment: @jlb I don't see method chaining here.

Comment: This is a simplification of the code to explain the problem clearly with a short example. The $_city var really has a value, but the method city() returns nothing when I call $firstClassObject->city() in the second object method maybe because I'm doing something wrong passing the parameters.

Comment: @bazmegakapa i swear i saw it in there.. my bad!

Comment: @Jimmy, ensure you have ini_set('display_errors', 1); and error_reporting(E_ALL); -- that might help. it seems like your issue lies elsewhere..

Comment: What about `return $this->_city`? :)

Comment: @Quasdunk Yes, I'm too drunk to stackoverflow. Retiring :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa n/m, I think we all know that feeling... :-D

Comment: @Jimmy: take more care not to describe what you [guess is the problem](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms) and stick to what's going wrong. That is, describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't lie in the call to `TheFirstClass::city` within `TheSecondClass::myMethod`, but rather that `TheFirstClass::city` returns a local variable (`$_city`) rather than an instance variable (`$this->_city`). Unlike in languages such as C++, in PHP instance variables must always be accessed through an object, even in methods.

This is the working code:

```
class TheFirstClass {
    private $_city = "a";

    public function city() {
        return $this->_city;
    }   
}

class TheSecondClass {
    public function myMethod($firstClassObject) {
        echo "City: " . $firstClassObject->city(); // <- Why This method doesn´t work?
    }
}

$test = new TheFirstClass();
$test2 = new TheSecondClass();
$test2->myMethod($test);
```

Comment: A good example why it's a good reason to enable error reporting in dev environments and pay attention (even to notices). I believe this would have been picked up if you had...